# IF condition not working in trigger

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, triggers, cursor

I have a trigger that is manage bulk loads from another table. When a bulk load of rows are inserted into the Projects table. The trigger is fired, however the conditions don't work for when the rows already exist in the inserted table.

The purpose of this trigger is to insert new rows that are inserted into the projects table to the vat_matrix table. If rows exist in the vat_matrix table then update them with the new values from the projects table.

I have tried a few options and found that the cursor is the only solution to iterate through the inserted rows. This works, however I can't get the if condition to work to update existing rows.

Are there any suggestions?

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[update_vat] ON [dbo].[projects]
FOR UPDATE, INSERT
AS

DECLARE @project AS VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @client AS VARCHAR(25) 
DECLARE @dim2 AS VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @period_from AS INT
DECLARE @period_to AS INT 
DECLARE @status AS CHAR(1)
DECLARE @user_id AS VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @unit_id AS VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @sequence_no AS INT 

SELECT @project = project,
@client = client,
@dim2 = dim2,
@period_from = period_from,
@period_to = period_to,
@status = status,
@user_id = user_id,
@unit_id = unit_id
FROM inserted

--FIND MAXIMUM VALUE FOR SEQUENCE NUMBER
SET @sequence_no = (SELECT MAX(v) FROM (SELECT sequence_no FROM agldefmatdet WHERE matrix_id = 11) AS value(v));

BEGIN

DECLARE tbl_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR

      SELECT project, client, dim2, period_from, period_to, status, user_id, unit_id FROM inserted


    SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE inserted.project = @project) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted WHERE deleted.project = @project)
  BEGIN

   OPEN tbl_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM tbl_cursor INTO @project, @client, @dim2, @period_from, @period_to, @status, @user_id, @unit_id

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[vat_matrix] 
        (att_val_from_1, 
            att_val_from_2,
            att_val_from_3,
            att_val_from_4,
            att_val_to_1,
            att_val_to_2,
            att_val_to_3,
            att_val_to_4, 
            att_value_1,
            att_value_2,
            att_value_3,
            att_value_4, 
            client, 
            dim_value, 
            last_update, 
            matrix_id, 
            period_from,
            period_to,
            sequence_no,
            status, 
            user_id)
    SELECT @project, 
            '', 
            '',
            '', 
            @project, 
            '', 
            '',
            '',
            @project, 
            '', 
            '',
            '',
            @client, 
            @dim2, 
            GETDATE(), 
            '11',
            '0',
            '0',
            @sequence_no + 1, 
            @status, 
            @user_id

      FETCH NEXT FROM tbl_cursor INTO @project, @client, @dim2, @period_from, @period_to, @status, @user_id, @unit_id

    --RETURN;

    END

    CLOSE tbl_cursor
    DEALLOCATE tbl_cursor

END

  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE inserted.project = @project) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted WHERE deleted.project = @project)
  BEGIN

  OPEN tbl_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM tbl_cursor INTO @project, @client, @dim2, @period_from, @period_to, @status, @user_id, @unit_id

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

    UPDATE vat_matrix
      SET dim_value = @dim2,
                last_update = GETDATE(),
                period_from = @period_from, 
                period_to = @period_to,
                status = @status,
                user_id = @user_id
                WHERE att_val_from_1 = @project 
                AND matrix_id = '11' 
                AND client = 'LU'

      FETCH NEXT FROM tbl_cursor INTO @project, @client, @dim2, @period_from, @period_to, @status, @user_id, @unit_id
    END

    CLOSE tbl_cursor
    DEALLOCATE tbl_cursor

    --RETURN;
END



END;
```

Comment: `CURSOR` inside a `Trigger`. Looks like a bad idea

Comment: I found its the only way to iterate through the new rows in the inserted table within the tigger. The only issue now is the if conditions

Answer (score 0):

As you said your trigger will work only when one row inserted at a time. Try using this trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[update_vat] 
ON [dbo].[projects] 
FOR UPDATE, INSERT 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @sequence_no AS INT 

      --FIND MAXIMUM VALUE FOR SEQUENCE NUMBER  
      SET @sequence_no = (SELECT Max(sequence_no)
                                  FROM   agldefmatdet 
                                  WHERE  matrix_id = 11)); 

      IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM   inserted) 
         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                         FROM   deleted) 
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[vat_matrix] 
                        (att_val_from_1, 
                         att_val_from_2, 
                         att_val_from_3, 
                         att_val_from_4, 
                         .....
                         user_id) 
            SELECT project, 
                   '', 
                   '', 
                   '', 
                   .....
                   user_id 
            FROM   inserted 
        END 

      IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM   inserted) 
         AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                     FROM   deleted) 
        BEGIN 
            UPDATE V 
            SET    dim_value = i.dim2, 
                   last_update = Getdate(), 
                   period_from = i.period_from, 
                   period_to = i.period_to, 
                   status = i.status, 
                   user_id = i.user_id 
            FROM   vat_matrix V 
                   JOIN inserted i 
                     ON v.att_val_from_1 = i.project 
            WHERE  matrix_id = '11' 
                   AND client = 'LU' 
        --RETURN;  
        END 
  END
```

Comment: Thanks Prdp, unfortunately this will only add one row in the vat_matrix table but add all rows in the projects table from the bulk insert. That was the reason for the cursor as the trigger only inserts once for every 5 rows.

Comment: @user3565164 - I could not find that condition in your current trigger. My code just do the same as your trigger does. Except that it will work in statement level also

Comment: Hi Prdp, thanks for the reply. Sorry - this works however the existing rows in the vat matrix don't get updated. They just get added in again - its the same for the projects table as well. Its driving me insane!

Comment: @user3565164 - According to your trigger `vat_matrix` table will get updated only when you update the `projects` table

Comment: Hi Prpd, yes thats right - so when I import the rows into the projects table the same rows are inserted rather than updated. I just reliesed would there need to be a check on the projects table rather than the matrix one?

Comment: @user3565164 - yes have a check if record already exist then update else insert